# Работа с массивом Python

Tags: python

У меня есть массив

```
n = [ 35, 40, 101, 59, 63 ]
```

Необходимо просуммировать последовательно каждый элемент, и если сумма элементов > 100 , то из общей суммы массива вычитаем max значение из оставшихся элементов.

1. 35+40+101=176
    176 >100
2. 63 > 59
3. 176+59 = 235

Как создать такой цикл?

Решение отредактировал:

```
array = [35, 40, 101, 59, 63]  # Ваш список.
numeral = 0
i = 0  # Переменная, равная числу итерации.
while numeral < 100:  # Цикл.
    numeral = numeral + array[i]  # Сложение чисел списка.
    i += 1
else:
    numeral = 0
    maximum_number = max(array[i:])  # Получаем максимальное число из оставшегося списка.
    array.remove(maximum_number)  # Удаляем из списка данное число.
    for numbers in array:  # Складываем оставшиеся числа.
        numeral = numeral + numbers
print (numeral)
```

Comment: Используйте цикл и просуммируйте

Comment: Что именно у вас вызвало затруднение - сложение элементов? написание оператора `if`? вызов функции `max`? вычитание одной переменной из другой?

Comment: Я только учусь) и не знаю как объединить все это.
Ну т.е. как создать такой цикл. Просто просуммировать все элементы я могу) отдельно вывести из массива макс и мин тоже.

А как сделать цикл, который все это включает?

Comment: Ну вот там прямо в цикле код которого вы добавили в вопрос и считайте и сумму и максимум. А после цикла уже `if` напишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одобренном решении есть пару неточностей, связанных с одним вариантом входных данных. А именно - что будет, если сумма чисел массива меньше 100? Ну например, входной массив - это 99 единиц? Ответ - ошибка индекса в операторе `numeral = numeral + array[i]`.
Вторая неточность. Допустим, наш исходный массив ровно 100 единиц. Тогда ошибка будет в операторе   `maximum_number = max(array[i:])` и вы получите сообщение: `max() arg is an empty sequence`, поскольку array[100:] в такум случае даст пустой список `[]`.
С учетом этих замечаний код мог бы выглядеть так:

```
arr = [35, 40, 101, 59, 63]  # Ваш список.

#arr = 101*[1]

sum_arr = 0
for i, num in enumerate(arr):
    sum_arr += num
    if sum_arr > 100:
        break

if i+1 == len(arr):
    if sum_arr > 100:
        print(f"Искомый результат = {sum_arr}")
    else:
        print(f"сумма ряда не больше 100 и равна {sum_arr}")
else:
    print(f"Искомый результат = {sum_arr - max(arr[i+1:]) + sum(arr[i+1:])}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов решения Вашей задачи:

```
array = [35, 40, 101, 59, 63]  # Ваш список.
numeral = 0
i = 0  # Переменная, равная числу итерации.
while numeral < 100:  # Цикл.
    numeral = numeral + array[i]  # Сложение чисел списка.
    i += 1
else:
    numeral = 0
    maximum_number = max(array[i:])  # Получаем максимальное число из оставшегося списка.
    array.remove(maximum_number)  # Удаляем из списка данное число.
    for numbers in array:  # Складываем оставшиеся числа.
        numeral = numeral + numbers
    required_number = numeral - maximum_number  # Данное число - ответ на Вашу задачу.
```

Comment: Для единообразия лучше `count` просто на `i` поменять :)

Comment: @gil9red , Благодарю, отрефакторил.

Comment: @6crimes если выводить print (required_number) , то выдает число 172, а должно 235

Comment: @Kishtaky Из Вашего условия "то из общей суммы массива вычитаем max значение из оставшихся элементов." следует, что из "235" необходимо так же вычесть максимальное значение оставшегося списка. Возможно, ошибка в Вашем условии или в представленном алгоритме действий.

Comment: @6crimes Да, возможно мою условие с ошибкой, но пошагово описал алгоритм.
т.е мы получили 176 (35+40+101) и к сумме 176 необходимо прибавить 59 (т.к оно меньше 63) и получить 235. 

Спасибо Вам огромное!!! подработал код под требование